# Адаптивность (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Вопрос глупый, конечно, но все же задам

на [странице](http://atomr-web.github.io/notify/) при малых разрешениях все очень мелко. Чяднт?

```
<header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="left-column col-md-5 col-sm-12">
                <h1>
                    Notify<span>.</span>
                </h1>
                <h2>
                    A great new free psd theme to showcase your new application.
                </h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="top-links">
                            <div class="app-link">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-apple"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="and-link">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-android"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="win-link">
                                <a href="#">
                                    <i class="fa fa-windows"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right-column">
            <img src="img/hand.png">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

css

```
@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
    .left-column h1,
    .left-column h2 {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .right-column {
        display: none;
    }

    .top-links {
        text-align: center;
    }
}
```

Скрин, как хотелось бы расположить блоки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я не наблюдаю чего-либо "мелкого" при разрешениях вплоть до 320px. У вас же у `header` задан `min-width: 600px;`. Добавьте скриншот, демонстрирующий проблему (обведите, что не так) или соберите минимальный пример для ее воспроизведения. А лучше и то, и другое сразу.

Comment: @VenZell min-width убрал, скрин добавил

Comment: @Atomrr попробуй обновить страницу. Вообще, ты должен видеть чуточку другое.

Comment: В Firefox автоматически сработал Zoom to fit, так что не сразу понял, в чем проблема

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас отсутствует необходимый мета-тег в `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Отсюда и проблемы с масштабированием контента.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое, то что нужно